prime react data table border thickness issue in electron app
I am Using prime react data table in my project , i am facing an issues with data tables and normal tables border thickness issue in my electron app , the same tables if i checking in chrome browser it is working fine, but in my laptop screen i am facing the border thickness issue
Can anyone please help me regarding the issue , below i am attaching the screen shot of my page which i took the screenshot from my electron app
